# Tikzpicture in figure problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, tikz-styles, adjustbox

Below is my MWE. My only problem is, I need the `tikzpicture` to be `pagewidth` (`textwidth`) and not overflow to the right. I tried `adjustbox`, `fbox` and `resizebox`.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im             
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{capt-of}


\tikzstyle{rounddiagram} = [
%\tikzset{
>=stealth',
punktchain/.style={
rectangle, 
rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
element/.style={
tape,
top color=white,
bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
minimum width=8em,
draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3.5em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
decoration={brace},
tuborg/.style={decorate},
tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
]%}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [style=rounddiagram, node distance=.8cm, start chain=going right]
    \node[punktchain, join]{FairRun};
    \node[punktchain, join]{Set I/O};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindClusters};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindHits};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: welcome to text.se. quick, dirthy hack: add `scale=0.8, transform shape,`. i would reduce size of nodes and fonts inside it.

Comment: Thanks, but thats too dirty. Don't to mess with that until it finally fits. The paper is rather of importance. Thanks though!

Comment: Another dirty solution is put `\hspace{-7.5ex}` between `\begin{figure}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always compute the maximal width the nodes should have to fill the full page precisely. We need `4*(space taken by a node)+3*(node distance)=\textwidth`, where `space taken by a node=(text width) + 2*(inner sep)+2*(outer sep)`. Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im             
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{capt-of}


\tikzset{rounddiagram/.style={>=stealth'},
punktchain/.style={
rectangle, 
rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
% line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
% element/.style={
% tape,
% top color=white,
% bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
% minimum width=8em,
% draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
% text width=10em, 
% minimum height=3.5em, 
% text centered, 
% on chain},
every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
% decoration={brace},
% tuborg/.style={decorate},
% tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounddiagram, node distance=.8cm, start chain=going right]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mynodewidth}{(\textwidth-3*0.8cm)/4-4pt}
    \begin{scope}[punktchain/.append style={text width=\mynodewidth pt,inner sep=1pt,outer
    sep=1pt}]
    \node[punktchain, join]{FairRun};
    \node[punktchain, join]{Set I/O};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindClusters};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindHits};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The output suggests that you may either want to write the text of the third node in two lines, have different widths for different nodes or to make them smaller by using `scale=(something <1)` in the nodes.

Let's assume you only want to scale the text. The scale factor that makes the picture precisely fit can be computed as follows.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im             
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,arrows}


\tikzset{rounddiagram/.style={>=stealth'},
punktchain/.style={
rectangle, 
rounded corners, 
draw=black, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt}}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rounddiagram, node distance=.8cm, start chain=going right]
    \def\myLst{FairRun,Set I/O,CbmStsFindClusters,CbmStsFindHits}
    \def\mywidth{0}
    \foreach \X [count=\Y] in \myLst
    {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{max(width("\X"),\mywidth)}
     \xdef\mywidth{\mywidth}
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mynodewidth}{(\textwidth-3*0.8cm)/4-4pt}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{(\mynodewidth-4)/\mywidth}
    \foreach \X in \myLst
    \node[punktchain,join,text width=\mynodewidth pt,inner sep=1pt,outer
    sep=1pt]{\scalebox{\myscale}{\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, all you need to do is to supply the code with the list `\myLst` which contains the texts, everything else is automatic.

Comment: Thanks, that's the cleanest way for me, though it's more complicated.
But really works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

i would change `text width` with `minimum width` which i would reduce to smaller size, for example to `7em`. also I would all doubled TikZ libraries and use `tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle`:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                calc, chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols,
                trees
                }

\usepackage{capt-of}


\tikzset{rounddiagram/.style = {
>=stealth',
punktchain/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw, very thick,
                     minimum width=7em, % <--- changed from "text width"
                     minimum height=5ex,
                     align=center, on chain},
      line/.style = {draw, thick, <-},
   element/.style = {tape, draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
                     top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
                     text width=10em, minimum height=7ex,
                     align=center, on chain},
every join/.style = {->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
       decoration = {brace},
    tuborg/.style = {decorate},
   tubnode/.style = {midway, right=2pt},
}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[style=rounddiagram,
node distance=5mm,
start chain=going right,
punktchain/.append style = {join}
                        ]
\node[punktchain] {FairRun};
\node[punktchain] {Set I/O};
\node[punktchain] {CbmStsFindClusters};
\node[punktchain] {CbmStsFindHits};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked better than the scale option and wasn't dirty, though I stick to marmots answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches:

As @Zarko mentioned, you can change the font and reduce the size of the `text width`. The second approach is to leave everything the same and add `transform canvas={xshift = 0.8cm}` to `tikzpicture` options.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im             
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}

\usepackage{capt-of}


\tikzstyle{rounddiagram} = [
%\tikzset{
>=stealth',
punktchain/.style={
rectangle, 
rounded corners, 
% fill=black!10,
draw=black, very thick,
text width=7.5em, 
minimum height=3em, 
text centered, 
font = \footnotesize,
on chain},
line/.style={draw, thick, <-},
element/.style={
tape,
top color=white,
bottom color=blue!50!black!60!,
minimum width=8em,
draw=blue!40!black!90, very thick,
text width=10em, 
minimum height=3.5em, 
text centered, 
on chain},
every join/.style={->, thick,shorten >=1pt},
decoration={brace},
tuborg/.style={decorate},
tubnode/.style={midway, right=2pt},
]%}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [style=rounddiagram, node distance=.8cm, start chain=going right]
    \node[punktchain, join]{FairRun};
    \node[punktchain, join]{Set I/O};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindClusters};
    \node[punktchain, join]{CbmStsFindHits};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [style=rounddiagram, node distance=.8cm, start chain=going right, transform canvas={xshift = 0.8cm}]
    \node[punktchain, join, text width=10em, font =\normalsize]{FairRun};
    \node[punktchain, join, text width=10em, font =\normalsize]{Set I/O};
    \node[punktchain, join, text width=10em, font =\normalsize]{CbmStsFindClusters};
    \node[punktchain, join, text width=10em, font =\normalsize]{CbmStsFindHits};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well, but I stick to marmots answer. :)

Comment: @Rhynden As you wish! He always have neat solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, node distance=2.5cm, auto]
    % Nodes
    \node (stress) {Stress Levels};
    \node (decision) [below left=of stress] {Decision-Making Skills};
    \node (thinking) [below right=of stress] {Critical-Thinking Skills};
    \node (environment) [below=of stress] {School Environment};
    \node (experiences) [below=of decision] {Personal Experiences};
    \node (interactions) [below=of thinking] {Peer Interactions};
    \node (outcome) [below=of environment, align=center] {Academic\\Performance/Well-being};

    % Arrows
    \draw[->] (stress) -- (decision);
    \draw[->] (stress) -- (thinking);
    \draw[->] (decision) -- (outcome);
    \draw[->] (thinking) -- (outcome);
    \draw[->] (environment) -- (outcome);
    \draw[->] (experiences) -- (outcome);
    \draw[->] (interactions) -- (outcome);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Conceptual Paradigm: Stress Levels, Decision-Making, and Critical-Thinking Skills}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```